# How to understand "All could devil set me free"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I'm listening to this song "A Whisper in the Noise - All my.."

> All could devil set me free
>
> I'm so tired I can't sleep
>
> All my feelings gravity's
>
> Spinning in the world over me
>
> > 
>
> Falling into masses empathy
>
> Very cementic energy
>
> Circle in the novel, sea to sea
>
> All could devil set me free
>
> ....

I can't figure out the meaning of `All could devil set me free`.

My guests:

1. All that devil can do is to set me free
2. All could set my devil free

What is the correct meaning and how can I get the meaning here? What are the leads and rules?

Comment: Do note that song lyrics do not necessarily mean anything, as songwriters are allowed a high degree of [artistic license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license). The lyricist is not always telling a story; sometimes, words are chosen because they evoke certain images or emotions, or because they fit a certain pattern of rhythm or rhyme. There are various sites like Genius.com or SongMeanings.com where people debate what they think lyrics of various songs are supposed to mean, but ultimately, only the writer can tell you if there was anything specifically intended.

Answer (score 2):

I found another version of the lyrics, which has 'All good devils set me free', which makes slightly more sense: bad devils torment me in hell, but good devils set me free (which means they're not really devils).

Where did you get these lyrics? Online versions of song lyrics are sometimes of variable quality.

Comment: got it [here](https://www.smule.com/song/a-whisper-in-the-noise-all-my-karaoke-lyrics/5176605_5176605/arrangement)

Comment: I second this statement: "**Online versions of song lyrics are sometimes of variable quality**". Most lyrical content available on the internet are based on what the listener who posted it comprehends from the song. There can be multiple comprehensions of the same song, by various listeners.